# How do I connect two controllers?

Tags: javafx, controller, fxml

I have two controllers. The first controller comprises List. The second controller offers various fxml relative to the selected element in List. These fxml contains a button that takes the value true when pressed. 
I can not get pass this value in the first controller to perform further action. 
How do I connect two controllers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

Comment: No, this topic has not solved my problem

Comment: Can you explain why that doesn't answer your question? How are the two FXML files being loaded, and what is the relationship between them? You just need one controller to get a reference to the other (which the linked question essentially describes), but without knowing more about how you have set these up, it's impossible to help further.

Comment: It may like this -> http://i.imgur.com/tV9T2Cj.png

Comment: You're not providing enough information for anyone to be able to answer your question, and you haven't shown that it's not answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml. You need to provide more information if you want people to be able to help. It may help to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then edit your question.